# Determine the production vector x that will satisfy demand in an economy with the given consumption matrix C and final demand vector d.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying for an exam and came across this problem in the book. Any ideas how one would go about solving this problem?

Determine the production vector x that will satisfy demand in an economy with the given consumption matrix C and final demand vector d. Round production levels to the nearest whole number.

[image]

Comment: I don't know much about economics. Are they asking you to solve $Cx=d$?

Answer (score 1):

Ok you need to solve $x=Cx+d$ or equivalently $(I-C)x=d$ where $I$ is the 2 by 2 identity matrix. This is equivalent to solving the system of equations $.6x_1-.3x_2=52$ and $-.1x_!+.4x_2=76.$

See [Leontief Input-Output Model examples](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/asavag2/mat1302/exercises/mat1302-input-output-model-exercises-solutions.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This is simply solving linear equations $Cx=d$ where $
x=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$
now you could just do this by using algebra, but I will use matrix algebra to do so. The answer will be of the form $x=C^{-1}d$ where we find $C^{-1}$ as follows
$$C^{-1}=\frac{1}{det(C)}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    .6&-.3 \\
    -.1&.4 \\
  \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{.21}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    .6&-.3 \\
    -.1&.4 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$
so we have that 
$$x=\frac{1}{.21}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    .6&-.3 \\
    -.1&.4 \\
  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    52 \\
    76 \\
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    40\\
    120 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Note the reason why we are solving a linear equation here interms of the question is because questons says we want production amount that satisfies demand meaning you have enough supply to meet demand (ie supply=demand)

Comment: You are close, however you should first subtract I - C. Then you should take the inverse of that result. From the inverse you should multiply it by the demand vector and you'll have your result.